# multiplicands:factors::addends:______?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, synonyms

When two multiplicands are multiplied, we get a product. But when we factorize the product, we split it into factors.

Similarly, when we add two addends, we get a sum. What do we call the resulting numbers when we split the sum? definitely not addends.

Taking a little further, what do we call the numbers which are result of splitting a difference, I wonder.

Comment: The reverse of multiplication is division. You're talking about a different, unspecified procedure that you're calling "splitting", and define as "reversing the process" in some way. No examples are given of "splitting" so it's quite unclear what you're asking, or even if the question is coherent.

Comment: @JohnLawler, the splitting i refer to is nothing but factorization in the case of multiplication. In case of addition and subtraction, I don't know what to call.

Comment: But factorization doesn't produce a unique output (3 x 4 is 12, and so is 2 x 6), and it doesn't work in every case (17 has no factors), so it's not continuous and not a function, let alone an algorithm, or the reverse of one. The fact that English a rare word _multiplicand_ and a common one _factor_, from two sources, with the same meaning (though the verb _factor_ is a different story) is nothing new; nobody ever says _multiplicand_ except in grammar school books. Nobody ever says _addend_, either. There's always at least N possible combinations of numbers that add to N, so we don't need it.

Comment: @JohnLawler, regardless of a non-unique result, 3x4, 6x2, 3x2x2, are called factors. So in my words, a factor is a generalized term for a number that is capable of dividing a product. Moreover, prime numbers also have exactly two factors eg 17 has 1x17. Since *multiplicand* has a commonly used synonym, I thought perhaps *addend* too has a commonly used one so that it can be used in a sentence like: *The score increased by a ______ of two.* (I very well remember that we can say *"The score increased by two."* but I am curious to fill that blank.)

Comment: @JohnLawler, I am sorry if above comment changed the context of the question.

Comment: @GregLee, Is it possible to say **multiplicands:factors::addends:terms**? I appreciate if you give some live example.

Comment: Tabrez, the parts of an arithmetic progression are called "terms" (do a web search on "arithmetic progression" for examples), and in programming, when giving a general syntactic characterization of a mathematical expression in a line of code, an entire expression is sometimes given as a sum of terms (each of which can be a product).  I'm not sure how to interpret your formula.

Comment: @GregLee, Your reply was verily helpful, thankyou. Let us together wait for a good answer from an English Scholar.

Comment: @TabrezAhmed: FYI, Greg Lee **is** an English Scholar. He's an old colleague of mine. You can trust what he tells you about English.

Comment: @GregLee, I didn't know you are an english scholar. I'm sorry if I've offended you....

Answer (score 2):

As Greg Lee says in the comments, the individual pieces of a sum are generally called *terms*.

In [number theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)), if you have 6+4+3+1, this is called a *partition* of 14 into four *parts*. However, this terminology is only used if the parts are positive integers.

Answer (score 0):

I will step aside for the fine, existing answers of Greg Lee and Peter Shor, which answer the former part of the OP's question.

The latter part of the OP's question was "what do we call the numbers which are result of splitting a difference."

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtraction), in defining subtraction, also includes definitions for *subtrahend* and *minuend*.

> All of this terminology derives from Latin. "Subtraction" is an English word derived from the Latin verb *subtrahere*, which is in turn a compound of sub "from under" and *trahere* "to pull"; thus to subtract is to draw from below, take away.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtraction) Using the gerundive suffix -nd results in "subtrahend", "thing to be subtracted".[2] Likewise from *minuere* "to reduce or diminish", one gets "minuend", "thing to be diminished".

So in `17 - 4 = 13`, 17 is the minuend (number being diminished); 4 is the subtrahend (number being subtracted) and 13 is the difference.